# Is it illegal for an actual minor to catch predators?

Tags: minor, sexual-assault

So a close friend of mine is a minor (close to not being) but we were wondering if it is illegal for her to pose as herself and report predators?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could vigilante anti paedophile sting operations actually result in a conviction?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/26256/could-vigilante-anti-paedophile-sting-operations-actually-result-in-a-conviction)

Comment: Consider that it is risky. Consider what might happen if she puts someone into jail for ten years and then the person comes out. Leave it to police.